# How do I make a kinematic body (3d) follow a player

Tags: godot, gdscript

I've been making a FPS in Godot and I'm having a hard time getting the kinematic body (the enemy) to go towards the player. Could someone please help?

Comment: Can you please expand on what you've tried so far and what your issue is? What code have you tried? Whats the error?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to get the player's position, compare it to the enemy position, and make the enemy move towards it every frame.

*Full example code is at the bottom.*

1. To get the player's position you first need a reference to it. You can usually do this through storing the reference in global singleton ([autoload](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html)) or by exposing a public property.

   - If you are doing it with a global singleton, then you get the position by calling `var player_position = my_singleton.player.global_transform.origin`
   - If you are using an exported property, then you would get the position by calling `var player_position = get_node(path_to_player).global_transform.origin`
2. Once you have the player position, you can compare it to the enemy by writing `var direction_to_target = player_position - global_transform.origin` from inside the enemy node.
3. Now in order to follow the player, we override the `_physics_process` method with something like this:

```
### Inside the enemy script

var ENEMY_SPEED= 50
func _physics_process(delta):
    var player_position = my_singleton.player.global_transform.origin
    var direction_to_target = (player_position - global_transform.origin).normalized() # We normalize the vector because we only care about the direction
    move_and_slide(direction_to_target * ENEMY_SPEED) # We multiply the direction by the speed
```